# Router.router path param is empty

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I have a API，created by **val router = Router.router(vertx)**
router.patch("/api/v2/user/:userId/names")

if user id is not passed getting message -  "error": "Page not found: /api/v2/user//names"

How can I give a default value if not passed or have another good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can't give a default value, you have to define another route.

```
val router = Router.router(vertx)
router.patch("/api/v2/user/names")
router.patch("/api/v2/user/:userId/names")
```

From a REST API design perspective, these are two different resources.

Comment: Understood.
If user id is not passed，how could i change the url of two "//" to one "/"? 
So that "router.patch("/api/v2/user/names") " can be called successful.

Comment: I believe Vert.x normalizes the URL already